# Remove item from list by value

Tags: c#, class

I have a list of class objects and want to remove one item but it doesn´t work:

```
    class Person
    {
        public string name; 
        public Person(string s)
        {
            this.name = s;
        }
    }

    void ABC()
    {
        List<Person> newPersonList = new List<Person>();
        newPersonList.Add(new Person("A"));
        newPersonList.Add(new Person("B"));
        newPersonList.Add(new Person("C"));

        newPersonList.Remove(A);
        newPersonList.RemoveAt(1);
    }
```

RemoveAt(1) works and deletes item with the ID 1.

I think Remove(A) should delete the item with the value "A". But this is not working. Can someone explain why? And what is the right way to delete by value?

Comment: What do you think should happen at `Remove(A);`? You haven't declared `A`. In general you need to override `Equals` in `Person` or/and implement `IEquatable<Person>`

Answer (score 30):

Easiest way to remove from list by element's property value:

```
newPersonList.RemoveAll(p => p.name == "A");
```

Nicer way would be to change `Person` like that:

```
class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public Person(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentException("name");
        Name = name;
    }
    public static implicit operator string(Person p)
    {
        return p.Name;
    }
    public static implicit operator Person(string name)
    {
        return new Person(name);
    }
    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }
}
```

And then use it like that:

```
var newPersonList = new List<Person>
{
    new Person("A"),
    new Person("B"),
    new Person("C")
};
newPersonList.Remove("A");
```

Or even like that:

```
var newPersonList = new List<Person> { "A", "B", "C" };
newPersonList.Remove(new Person("A"));
```

Comment: He can use `newPersonList.RemoveAll(p => p.name == "A")`. Your approach needs to scan the list twice. But better is to override `Equals` in `Person` or let it implement `IEquatable<Person>`. Then `Remove` works as expected.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Average complexity is better for my solution =)

Comment: @astef No, your solution *doesn't* have a lower average complexity.  It does more work, not less.

Comment: @astef: also, if there is no person with name="A" your approach throws an error. If you use `FirstOrDefault` to prevent that you delete a person which is `null`. Your second aproach works only by accident since references are compared. OP wants to compare by name.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Agree with everything. I've edited my answer following your advices

Answer (score -1):

You have not declared A. To do `newPersonList.Remove(A);`

You have to declare an object Person A and add it to newPersonList

```
Person A = new Person("A");
newPersonList.Add(A);
```

Answer (score -1):

Like other said "What is `A`?". If it would be a variable that contains a `Person` that this will work.

```
void ABC()
{
    var A = new Person("A");
    var B = new Person("B");
    var C = new Person("C");
    List<Person> newPersonList = new List<Person>();
    newPersonList.Add(A);
    newPersonList.Add(B);
    newPersonList.Add(C);

    newPersonList.Remove(A);
}
```